# Simple C++ program is not linking on Windows under MingW

Tags: c++, mingw

I do not know why I cannot link this program.  First off this is my header file, gcd.h:

```
#ifndef GCD_H
#define GCD_H

/**
 * Calculate the greatest common divisor of two integers.
 * Note: gcd(0,0) will return 0 and print an error message.
 * @param a the first integer
 * @param b the second integer
 * @return the greatest common divisor of a and b
 */

long gcd(long a, long b);

#endif
```

And this is my gcd.cpp file:

```
#include "gcd.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long gcd(long a, long b) {

    // if a and b are both zero, print an error and return 0
    if ( (a==0) && (b==0) ) {
        cerr << "WARNING: gcd called with both arguments equal to zero." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Make sure a and b are both nonnegative
    if (a<0) {
        a = -a;
    }
    if (b<0) {
        b = -b;
    }

    // if a is zero, the answer is b
    if (a==0) {
        return b;
    }

    // otherwise, we check all the possibilities from 1 to a
    long d; // d will hold the answer

    for (long t=1; t<=a; t++) {
        if ( (a%t==0) && (b&t==0) ) {
            d = t;
        }
    }

    return d;
}
```

The main problem is when I compile, it returns the error

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2):
>   undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

I don't understand what that means.

Please help?

Okay actually can someone just modify my code so it runs properly?  That's the best bet at this point because then I'll actually understand what I did wrong.

Comment: what compiler are you using? i'm guessing gcc because of the paths included in the error message

Comment: He/She is using the GCC. You can see it in their path.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: There are much more efficient ways of implementing GCD, you should try to google for better solutions.

Comment: @Glassjawed: If you're passing `-mwindows` to GCC, don't.

Comment: I know there are better solutions but I was just writing this one from the textbook just so I could see how the code was supposed to work.  I could use Euclid's algorithm instead.

Comment: What does that mean?  How would I be passing -mwindows to GCC and how do I correct that?

Answer (score 5):

where is your `main` function (the entry point of the program..)?

Btw I like that you wrote "the main problem" :)

Comment: it looks like it's expecting a winmain function as well.. probably it's being compiled for winapi or something like that..

Comment: C:\Users\Yannik\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLumP2t.o:testing.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `gcd(long, long)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status is the compiler error I get when I do...

Comment: `#include "gcd.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * A program to test the gcd procedure.
 */
int main() {
 long a,b;

 cout << "Enter the first number --> ";
 cin >> a;
 cout << "Enter the second number ---> ";
 cin >> b;

 cout << "The gcd of " << a << " and " << b << " is "
  << gcd(a,b) << endl;
 return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a program, it's a single function.

It can be independently compiled, but it can't be linked into an executable because it has no entry point.  The linker is complaining about the missing entry point (according to the name expected by your compiler's startup code).

Comment: How could it be independently compiled?  It gave an error when I tried to do that.

Also I tried linking and that didn't work.

Comment: `#include "gcd.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * A program to test the gcd procedure.
 */
int main() {
 long a,b;

 cout << "Enter the first number --> ";
 cin >> a;
 cout << "Enter the second number ---> ";
 cin >> b;

 cout << "The gcd of " << a << " and " << b << " is "
  << gcd(a,b) << endl;
 return 0;
}`

Comment: (included the header file which invokes the gcd function)

Comment: @Glassjawed: It can be independently compiled with the `-c` option... `g++ -c gcd.cpp`.  Then the resulting object file can be linked into your main program: `g++ main.cpp gcd.o`

Comment: What does g++ -c mean?  I'm just curious.

Comment: @Glassjawed: `-c` means "compile, do not link".  You get an object file which can be used when another compilation unit gets linked.  Often there's a step along the way of creating a static library, but objects can be directly linked as well.

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling your code? It should be something like:

```
g++ gcd.cpp -o gcd
```

Do not `#include <windows.h>` or add `-mwindows` to your command.

Comment: I'm not including -mwindows.  I got the undefined reference to WinMain error again. 

And if I am including -mwindows, how do I remove -mwindows?  I'm using EditPlus and I didn't explicitly say #include <windows.h> or anything.